# Guassian Sum Solving based on Improper Integral

Tags: calculus

We all know that:$$\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^{2}} \ dx = \sqrt{\pi}$$.

Now if we consider the sum:

$$\mathfrak{A} = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} 2^{-n^{2}}$$

Then how can we show $\mathfrak{A}$ in the form
$\left( q^{-m}; q^{-k} \right)_{\infty} \left( -q^{-n}; q^{-k} \right)_{\infty}^{2}$?

In which $q, m, n, k \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$ and $(\cdot; \cdot)_{k}$ is the q-Pochhammer symbol.

Comment: Your sum is just a value of the Jacobi theta function $$\Theta(x)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} e^{-n^2 \pi x}.$$ Look at the Wikipedia page http://mathworld.wolfram.com/JacobiThetaFunctions.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the Jacobi triple product
$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} x^{n^{2}}z^{n} = \prod_{i=1}^{\infty} (1-x^{2n+2})(1+x^{2n+1}z)(1+x^{2n+1}z^{-1})$$
when $|x| < 1$ and $z$ nonzero, we substitute $x = 2^{-1}$ and $z = 1$:
$$\mathfrak{A} = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} 2^{-n^{2}} = \prod_{i=1}^{\infty} (1-2^{-2i-2})(1+2^{-2i-1})^{2}$$
We can then see that
$$\mathfrak{A} = \prod_{i=0}^{\infty} (1-2^{-2i-4})(1+2^{-2i-3})^{2} = \left( 2^{-4}; 2^{-2} \right)_{\infty} \left( 2^{-3}; 2^{-2} \right)_{\infty}$$